# Invoking Modelstate.isValid

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller

On Form post, ModelState is valid if a value for Name has been entered by the user.

However, if no property value has been set for Name on Post *but* I explicitly set one in the action before calling ModelState.IsValid - it returns as invalid.

Can anyone think of a way around this, I've tried calling Validate(person) before ModelState but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Many thanks!

```
public class Person
    { [Required]
      public string Name {get; set;}
    }
```

Action

```
public ActionResult updateDetails(Person person)
{
    person.Name = "bob";
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    { doSomething(); }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to clear the model state and validate it again. Try `ModelState.Clear();` and then `TryValidateModel(person);`

Comment: @DavidG That seems to have done the trick, if you post it as an answer, I'll happily choose it as an answer. I've just wasted hours writing client-side code to get around this! - Many thanks, David :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the model state and validate it again. For example:

```
ModelState.Clear(); 
TryValidateModel(person);
```